# how to use path to image file

Tags: reactjs, path

I'm trying to load an image file in my reactjs project but it results in a broken image icon.. I'm loading the image from the `Test1.js` using `<img src='../logo-001.png' />`

here's my folder structure:

```
src
  components
    Test1.js // I'm loading it from this file
  logo-001.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use imports like:

```
import img from '../icon.png';
<img src={img} alt="img" />
```

Or put your img on the public folder and use it:

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img.png'} alt="img" />
```

If you still has problems, probably is related with a problem I had with vue JS, I needed to disable the es-module on the file-loader, because it was messing with the resources path.

Comment: the import method works wonderful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try a simple another way to import image from your folder. below the code for example.

```
 import logo-001 from '../logo-001.png';  // Here the correct folder path should be given
 
  <img src={logo-001} alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: I'll try this later because I can only work on my react js project outside of office hour. but can we really use operators as part of a variable in the import section?